# Classifying the Next Call

Tags: time-series

Suppose I have calls that come from handsets A, B, C, and time series data aggregated like so:

```
CallDateTime        Buckets
1/11/15 4:52 PM     A
1/11/15 7:00 PM     B
1/11/15 10:43 AM    C
```

I have this data from 1/11 to 2/1, where each call has come in and has been stamped with either an A, B, or C. I want to predict the likelihood at any time of the next call being either an A, B, or C. How can I do this in R? I'm looking to improve on using historical averages, but I'm not even sure where to start or what to search to be honest. Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with some features which will give you some clues which bucket that call belongs to. The current information is only the call date & time (assuming independence). If historical data matters, then this is a good candidate for HMM or CRF.

Comment: Presumably "HMM" = "Hidden Markov Model" and "CRF" = "Conditional Random Field".  But how exactly would either of these models be applied in this circumstance?